# Is the usual topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ a borel set in $2^{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $\tau$ be the usual topology of $\mathbb{Q}$. As $\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can see $\tau$ as a subset of $2^{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is a Polish space.

I want to show that $\tau$ is a Borel set of $2^{\mathbb{Q}}$. 
Exactly, I want to show that $\tau$ is $\Pi^0_3(2^{\mathbb{Q}})$.

I think the following characterization of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be useful.

> It's well-known that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a unique, up to homeomorphism, countable perfect metric space.

Comment: Do you also need to show it's not of a lower class or is just being in that class enough? Remind us of its definition (a countable intersection of $\Sigma^0_2$-sets?)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, I don't, just being in that class enough. Do you think $\tau$ is $F_{\sigma}$ or $G_{\delta}$? A subset $\Pi^0_3$ is union countable of $\Sigma^0_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right! A $\Pi^0_3$ set is countable intersection of $\Sigma^0_2$ sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B_n(q)$ be the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ centered at $q$. Then

$$
X \in \tau 
\iff 
\forall q \in \mathbb{Q} . 
\exists n \in \mathbb{N} . 
\forall r \in B_n(q) . [ q \in X \implies r \in X]
$$

Put differently,

$$
\tau = 
\bigcap \limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} 
\bigcup \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
\bigcap \limits_{r \in B_n(q)}
N_{q,r}
$$

Where $N_{q,r} = \{ X ~|~ q \in X \implies r \in X \} = \{ X ~|~ q \not \in X \lor r \in X \}$ is clopen.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{N}$, and $B_n(q)$ are all countable, $\tau$ is $\Pi^0_3$, as desired.

---

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot @HallaSurvivor.  Do you think $\tau$ is $F_{\sigma}$ or $G_{\delta}$?

Comment: Intuition says no, but after trying for a while (and discussing it with some friends), I can't manage to prove it. I'll try for a while longer, and I'll comment here if I find anything ^_^